# After redirect my website from HTTP to HTTPS my popup becomes messy

Tags: asp.net, http, https, asp-classic

After redirect my asp.net website from HTTP to HTTPS my popup becomes messy and i don't know why ?!! and that's code

```
<a href="#inline_ReferFrnd" class="inline1" id="referToFriend"><%=Resources.LanguageFile.REFER_TO_FRIEND %></a>
<div style='display: none;'>
        <div id='inline_ReferFrnd' style='padding: 10px; background: #fff; background-image: url("App_Themes/_Main/images/bg.jpg");'>
            <div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtYourName"  CssClass="txt-box" Style=" border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #B0AEAD; margin-top: 1%;"
                            placeholder="Your name"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<button id="referToFrndBtn" onclick="SubmitRefer();" class="txt-box"
                            style="background-color: rgb(255, 210, 1); color: white; padding: 0%; padding-left: -1%; width: 29%; padding-bottom: 4%; padding-top: .5%; font-size: 101%; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid; padding-left: 4%; padding-right: 4%;">
                            <%=Resources.LanguageFile.SEND_EMAIL %></button> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by messy? Are all resources (images, css, js) loaded on the `https` connection or are some missing because they use a `http` url?

Comment: i mean by messy all resources in popup ! first i suspect the link is http but the link of popup is https

Comment: Just open Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools or FireBug and check what resources are not loaded. You are probably using absolute urls and your stylesheets are loaded from http, and browser just do not allows it